# Gradle setup multiple build scripts for the same project

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

For my project I have different setups that require a certain 3rd party library to be added to the classpath. Based on a keyword, I need to either add A.jar or B.jar to the classpath of the project.

I have worked out that I can use `-b` flag being able to specify a different build script. I however don't know how to tell gradle that the base path of the project is one level up. So, say this configuration:

```
/src/main/java
/build_scripts/buildA.gradle
              /buildB.gradle
```

Now, if I execute `gradle -b build_scripts/buildA.gradle` it does the right thing, however all generated files are routed in `build_scripts`.

1. So I was wondering, can I change the root directory for gradle when executing a different script file?
2. Is this the right approach to adding extra dependencies? I am trying to avoid having to do if-else statements in my build file. I could alternatively also just import a partial build file (if possible) that only defines the dependencies?

Comment: Is it just one jar that differs between the two gradle files? Or are there a whole bunch of differences? If the changes are fairly limited, I highly recommend using an if/then structure instead of two different build files. Every time you make changes to the common parts of one file, you have to remember to change the other two, I guarantee you this will come back to bite you at some point in the future when you forget.

Comment: 2. Why not put both buildscripts in the root directory?

Comment: 3. You don't have to change the root directory, you can just change the build directory, which changes where the generated files go. `project.buildDir='..\build'`

Comment: @RaGe there are potentially multiple dependencies that may differ. So far i am using an if-else statement however this keeps growing which is starting to get annoying. i was wondering if i could also just have a plain text file for dependencies that i simply read in my dependency part and add those in. I will try the buildDir property soon and see how it works. I agree though that having to repeat common parts for each build.gradle would be annoying and a risk of missing/forgetting details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a good reason to use configurations!  So let's imagine we want to use three different versions of a jar depending on what we are building.  For this example we will use three versions of `gson`

```
apply plugin: "java"

version = '0.1'
configurations {
    // let configurations that extend compile all the compile classpath entries
    compile.transitive = true
    // define a configuration
    one {
        description = 'compile configuration one\'s classpath'
        extendsFrom compile
    }
    // create another configuration
    two {
        description = 'compile configuration two\'s classpath'
        extendsFrom compile
    }
}

// let gradle know you want a jar from configuration named `one`
task('oneJar', type: Jar) {
    // define what configuration our jar contains
    from configurations.one
    // set the name so we know which jar is which configuration
    baseName = "$project.name-$configurations.one.name"
}

// let gradle know you want a jar from configuration named `two`
task('twoJar', type: Jar) {
    // define what configuration our jar contains
    from configurations.two
    // set the name so we know which jar is which configuration
    baseName = "$project.name-$configurations.two.name"
}

// make gradle build our other configuration jars anytime it runs the jar task
jar.dependsOn oneJar, twoJar

// boilerplate repository to look for dependencies
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

// here we can define configuration specific dependencies
dependencies {
    // will only appear in the "${project.name}-${project.version}.jar" file
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4"
    // will only appear in the "${project.name}-one-${project.version}.jar" file
    one "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1"
    // will only appear in the "${project.name}-two-${project.version}.jar" file
    two "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7"
}
```

Next we can verify our configurations via the gradle task `dependencies`

```
$ ./gradlew dependencies --configuration compile
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

compile - Dependencies for source set 'main'.
\--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.969 secs

$ ./gradlew dependencies --configuration one
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

one - compile configuration one's classpath
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4 -> 2.6.1
\--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.828 secs

$ ./gradlew dependencies --configuration two
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

two - compile configuration two's classpath
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4 -> 2.7
\--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.764 secs
```

And we can verify an artifact has been produced for each configuration

```
$ ls -l build/libs/
total 824
-rw-r--r--  1 some.user  63209268  207741 Nov 15 14:05 gradleConfigurations-one-0.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 some.user  63209268  208665 Nov 15 14:05 gradleConfigurations-two-0.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 some.user  63209268     930 Nov 15 14:05 gradleConfigurations-0.1.jar
```

Comment: This looks like an elegant solution. I will give this a try tomorrow morning :)

Comment: I had to use --configuration-on-demand and then this works really nice - i like that configuration. Is there a way to enable that for the eclipse plugin as well? Currently (I think) eclipse ends up with all dependencies, while the jar does the right thing

Comment: You can enable the configuration on demand in the `gradle.properties`

Comment: I've tried this solution - why builds one and two are much bigger than this without configuration? (In my case the size increased from 197kB to 9 MB)

Comment: @rudald, Probably better to open a new question to completely understand your issue.